# Checking whether post_parent = 0 in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a site using WordPress using a theme which has this PHP at the top of each page and I am confused as to what it does.

```
<?php 
global $post;
global $wp_query;
if ( $post->post_parent != 0 ) {
    $thePostID = $post->post_parent;
} else {
    $thePostID = $wp_query->post->ID;
};
?>
```

I was just wondering if anyone could explain exactly what this does? I think it checks to see if the `post_parent` `id` is `0` which isn’t allowed in WordPress and sets the post `id` to the `post_parent` but I’m not 100% sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I think it checks to see if the post_parent id is 0 which isn’t allowed in WordPress

The `$post->post_parent` is allowed to be `0`. If the value is `0`, it simply means that the page is a top level page.

A page that has a `$post->post_parent` other than `0`, is a child of another page.

For example, take this page structure as an example:

```
id      page_title    post_parent
1       Home          0
2       About         0
3       Staff         2
4       History       2
5       Contact       0
```

The resulting page/menu structure would be:

- Home
- About
- Staff
- History
- Contact

The code in question:

```
if ($post->post_parent != 0) {
    $thePostID = $post->post_parent;
} else {
    $thePostID = $wp_query->post->ID;
}
```

I'm not sure why your theme might have the code, but a possible reason might be to get a menu related to the current page. If you're viewing the top level page (i.e. `$post->post_parent == 0`), then it would show all child pages, or if you're viewing a sub page, the menu might show all sibling pages.

### A sample menu generated using this method

Add this to your `functions.php` file so it's accessible throughout the theme.

```
/**
 * Get top parent for the current page
 *
 * If the page is the highest level page, it will return its own ID, or
 * if the page has parent(s) it will get the highest level page ID. 
 *
 * @return integer
 */
function get_top_parent_page_id() {
    global $post;
    $ancestors = $post->ancestors;

    // Check if the page is a child page (any level)
    if ($ancestors) {
        // Get the ID of top-level page from the tree
        return end($ancestors);
    } else {
        // The page is the top level, so use its own ID
        return $post->ID;
    }
}
```

Add this code to your theme where you want to display a menu. You will need to customise it to suit your particular needs, but it gives you an example of why someone might use the code you asked about.

```
// Get the highest level page ID
$top_page_id = get_top_parent_page_id();

// Display basic menu for child or sibling pages
$args = array(
    'depth'        => 1,
    'title_li'     => FALSE,
    'sort_column'  => 'menu_order, post_title',
    'child_of'     => $top_page_id
);
echo wp_list_pages($args);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, that would be great if you could post some sample code.

Comment: @pocockn I've add an example for you.

Comment: This should be part of the documentation for `wp_get_post_parent_id()`

Answer (score 0):

So as far as i see, this snippet does the following:

1. Loads the global post object.
2. Loads the global query object.
3. Checks (or tries to check) if the current post has a parent filter (?).
4. If it has, it sets the variable $thePostID to the id of the post_parent parameter of the current post object.
5. If it hasnt, it sets the post id in the wp_query to the id of the current post.

All together, this seems very unnecessary, bad performing and strange Oo.
Does ist work actually? ^^

I would advise you on using another theme if possible ;-)